# Powershell: speeding up GCI on large volume of files in a directory

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a directory with over approx. 20,000 XML files, that are built up each day. Each file is an order file, containing an "order date" attribute. I need to retrieve files, every day, that contain an order date of today's date. This is easy enough using XPATH, but rather than go through all files in the directory, I have limited the search where the "LastWriteTime" is greater than a "date" (yesterday @ 4:40pm).

Here is my snippet:

```
$Date = (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd)
$YesterdayCutoff = (Get-Date -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-1).AddHours(16.5)
gci $Path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $Yesterdaycutoff} | 
Select-Xml -XPATH //Order/@OrderDate | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node | Where {$_."#text" -match $Date}
```

On average there is about 450 files within this range, but still takes up to 4 minutes to execute and I have many other similar scripts to run. Is there any other quicker way to execute this more efficiently?

Comment: Use XPath: `"//Order[@OrderDate='$date']"` or `"//Order[contains(@OrderDate,'$date')]"` and remove select-object and where.

Comment: There would be if you could name your files systematically. A wildcard search is much faster than a time-based search. Alternatively, archive stuff that no longer needs processing.

Comment: Can't you parallelize the last part?

Comment: Another trick you could consider: filter the files some more first using `Select-String $Date`. Raw string filtering is orders of magnitude faster than parsing XML. Of course, afterwards you should still parse them "properly" to see if they don't match accidentally, so this is only of benefit if most files, in fact, *don't* match.

Comment: Also worth a try `$List = (gci $Path).Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt $Yesterdaycutoff}; $List | Select-Xml -XPATH [...]` The pipe is pretty damn slow in powershell.

Comment: Soo its a little hacky but robocopy is MUCH faster at listing files with a timstamp filter than gci is.  you do however have to parse the output into a usable object yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the original filenames cannot be sorted or identifiable in any useable way other than by the timestamp of the file. This folder is already archived and 20k files is the leanest we can achieve. Will try these suggestions, however with wOxxOm's solution, I get an error: Select-Xml : "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."